# Question about Present Perfect Subjunctive. Is it required?

Tags: present-perfect, subjunctive-mood

Suppose that a dog is required by the terms of his doghouse arrest to maintain shaggy fur.

May I write:

> The condition that Fido *have* shaggy fur is restrictive.

I believe that this is a form of the present perfect subjunctive in English. Is it? It sounds better to my ear than

> The condition that Fido has shaggy fur is restrictive.

I believe that the second is wrong, though not too offensive to the ear and probably more common.

Can someone clarify the grammatical rules/context here?

EDIT: This was not the present perfect subjunctive, as has been pointed out. Still, this situation is somewhat strange because the once correct subjunctive is perceived as archaic by some.

Comment: I would write it: The condition that Fido must have shaggy hair is restritive. The avoids the ackwardness. Or even: The condition "Fido must have shaggy hair" is restrictive.

Comment: I'd say that your first example is a straightforward subjunctive where "have" is the plain (or base/infinitival) form of the verb, not the perfect auxiliary. It's very formal, to the point of being archaic, and I think your second example is better and sounds more natural.

Comment: The context is a formal mathematics paper. I am not discussing dogs and shaggy fur, but a formal object X with property P. Maybe I'm just an archaic person, but the first seems better than the second.

To be clear, both of you think that the first sentence is correct, you just think it sounds outdated?

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical, but I judged that particular use of the subjunctive to be archaic purely in the context of your actual example. Others may disagree, of course. Lambie's alternatives sound good to me.

Comment: 'Have' forms a perfect _only if it is followed by a past participle_. There is no perfect, of any kind, here. It is indeed usually analysed as subjunctive, and is rather formal.

Comment: @ColinFine What tense is used in the first sentence then? The context I care about is formal (as opposed to my silly example). I am curious how it is characterized grammatically. It feels like some form of the subjunctive to me, but I don't know much about grammar terminology.

Comment: @Lepidopterist Sorry to butt in, but I did say in my first comment that it was the 'subjunctive'. As I said, a subjunctive construction uses the plain (**untensed**) form of a verb, like "have" (not to be confused with the perfect "have" in something like _I have heard about Fido_ where "have" is an auxiliary verb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this sentence correct? “She suggested that he go to the cinema.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76550/why-is-this-sentence-correct-she-suggested-that-he-go-to-the-cinema)

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate, since this isn't about the present perfect subjunctive at all.

Comment: @PeterShor It's true that it isn't about the present perfect subjunctive, but it clearly isn't a duplicate of the linked question since it was suggested by many that the subjunctive was archaic in this context. I can edit the question, but then the answers lose their context. Please advise.

Comment: The constructions in this question and in the linked question are both the mandative subjunctive. This is viewed as archaic by many people in the U.K., but it is still widely used in the U.S. (at least in some regions, like New England, where I live). [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305792/the-condition-that-noun-be-adjective) is a slightly closer duplicate question.

Comment: @PeterShor The latter duplicate question is indeed a near match. If you reference that instead I'd be content.

Answer (score -1):

An present perfect subjunctive is rare. En.wikipedia in English subjunctive has an example.
Wikipedia:
Occasionally, a present perfect subjunctive is seen, as in

- It is important that he have completed two years of Spanish before graduation.[citation needed]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Comment: But hasn't it been established in the comments that neither of those examples uses the present perfect subjunctive? Not sure how you are answering my question about the grammatical context of what I am trying to convey.

Comment: I'm used to subjunctives in AmE, and that present perfect subjunctive just sounds weird. I don't think Americans use present perfect subjunctives often.

Comment: I can find it "in the wild." N.Y.Times, 1967: *The requirements are that the member be at least 25 years old, that he have been a citizen for seven years, and that he inhabit the state in which he was elected.* And 1823: *Surely it is requisite that he have been universally read and acknowledged.* But it seems incredibly rare. I would use the present perfect indicative in both places myself, unless I used substantially different wording.